# Asset Library doesn't work with Source Control

Tags: asset-browser

For our video game I figured setting up Asset Libraries would help artists work on connected models concurrently in source control.

As a test I have a base enemy model saved as an asset. Then in a separate file I add this base model as a link and model a set of armor. With this setup two people could be working on different sets of armor at the same time.

However, the file link is stored as an absolute path so it is broken on everyone else's computer.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to set up Asset Browser to work with links and version control?

Comment: I assume you have relative paths enabled in Preferences in the Save & Load Tab's Blend Files settings; and that people are aware that they need to save a new blend file before they bring in any files so that relative paths will work.  That said, unfortunately, the current version of Asset Libraries does indeed use hardwired paths.  Our solution is to have a well known directory present on every machine and place the asset libraries in that directory.  I don't know what you can do if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes, we have all those enabled. I had thought of that but forcing everyone to keep the project in a root folder so the path is consistent really isn't reasonable for us. 

I am wondering now though if there are parts of the python API that could get hooked into to ensure asset library links use relative paths or catalog ids somehow. I'm just not super familiar with what the blender api exposes and what is possible in that regard

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that.  Unfortunately, the Asset Library API isn't very well done yet and they're in the process of rewriting it. Unfortunately [T93774](https://developer.blender.org/T93774) is an open bug that's meant to eventually support relative paths.  Unfortunately the devs don't think it will happen anytime soon.

Comment: @MartyFouts gotcha. That is unfortunate - I was very excited about the asset browser feature. For now, we can just use the normal way to link files until the asset browser is more usable

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late reply, but I was looking into this as well. A workaround you can use is the **File/External Data/Make Paths Relative** command to convert all paths, then save your file.